# Getting oldest record from SQL Server using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, greatest-n-per-group

I have a T-SQL query where I need to find the oldest date record. I have written it like this:

```
SELECT
    T0.ItemCode, T0.OpenQty AS 'Qty', MIN(T1.DocDate) AS 'DocDate', 
    T1.DocNum, T1.CardCode, T1.SlpCode AS 'Sales Person', T0.WhsCode
FROM
    RDR1 T0
INNER JOIN
    ORDR T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
WHERE 
    T0.linestatus = 'O'
GROUP BY 
    T0.ItemCode, T0.OpenQty , T1.DocNum, T1.CardCode, T1.SlpCode , T0.WhsCode
```

but it is not returning the oldest date record.

Data is shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of DocDate? What output are you getting and what is your expected result?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to rank the records by ascending `T1.DocDate` in a inner query, and then select the oldest in the outer query:

```
Select *
From (
    Select  
        T0.ItemCode, 
        T0.OpenQty as 'Qty', 
        T1.DocDate,
        T1.DocNum, 
        T1.CardCode, 
        T1.SlpCode as 'Sales Person', 
        T0.WhsCode,
        Row_Number() Over(Order By T1.DocDate) rn
    From RDR1 T0
    Inner Join ORDR T1 on T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry
    Where T0.linestatus = 'O'
) x
Where rn = 1
```

This will give you the oldest record in the table. If you need to get the oldest record per group, then you can add a `PARTITION BY` clause to the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

Note: this also assumes that `T1.DocDate` is of a date-like datatype, which seems to be (and should be) the case by looking at your sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need a unique oldest record in each group. I tried Partition But it's not working. and yes its date type data type.

Comment: @AsifHameed: how do you define a group?

Comment: The values with the same itemcode and Qty are a group as highlighted in image. i want to pick the one with old date

Comment: @AsifHameed: ok so you would need `Row_Number() Over(Partition By T0.ItemCode, T0.OpenQty Order By T1.DocDate)`.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you writing Self join ?  If you need to get 10 oldest record from table then just sort the table according date in ascending order and list top 10 rows.

For Example -

```
Select  top 10 T0.ItemCode, T0.OpenQty as 'Qty', T1.DocDate as 'DocDate', T1.DocNum, T1.CardCode, T1.SlpCode as 'Sales Person', T0.WhsCode
From RDR1 T0
Where T0.linestatus = 'O'
order by T1.DocDate
```